# Create INSERT statement using parameter

Tags: sql, sql-server, stored-procedures

I need to create a INSERT statement using parameters. Say I have two variable name `@DestinationFields`, `@InsertValues`.

Here `@DestinationFields` contain the column name like: `product,price` and `@InsertValues` contains the values for those two columns, like: `Book,100`.

Now, How i create a insert command to insert those values where each value need to add a quotation mark .I already tried as

I already tried as

```
EXEC('INSERT into tbl_test('+@DestinationFields+')values('+@InsertValues+')')
```

But it's returning an error.

> *The name "book" is not permitted in this context. Valid expressions are constants, constant expressions, and (in some
>   contexts) variables. Column names are not permitted.*

How do I do it? Thanks in advance.

Comment: MAY be i can't clarify the question properly. Basically i need to add the quotation mark in each value. How i do it? because the values come into those variable exactly as i write.

Comment: Answers by dasblinkenlight:  select @sql = 'INSERT INTO tbl_test'    
     +'('+@DestinationFields+')values('''
     +REPLACE(@InsertValues,',',''',''')
     +''')'
Exec(@sql)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Pretending there is no problem of SQL injection here<sup>*</sup>, you can quickly fix your code by adding quotation marks around `Book`. The value of `@ InsertValues` should be

```
'Book', 100
```

instead of simply

```
Book, 100
```

You need to add quotation marks around each string value; otherwise, strings are interpreted as names, which is not valid.

**EDIT :** (in response to a comment) If all columns are of `varchar` type, you can put quotes around the entire string, and replace all commas with the quote-comma-quote pattern, like this:

```
values('''+REPLACE(@InsertValues,',',''',''')+''')'
```

---

<sup>*</sup> You should not put code like this into production, because it can be manipulated to harm your system rather severely. Here is a good illustration of the problem ([link](http://xkcd.com/327/)).

Comment: agreed with you. But i need to add the quotation

Comment: @riad The code that is preparing the `@InsertValues` is the only one that can possibly handle this, because other parts of your code do not know that `product` is a `varchar`, but `price` is a number.

Comment: consider each value as a var char.Now how i add the quotation mark on each value.

Comment: it's getting error: can you please help me to figure it out: EXEC('INSERT INTO '+@DestinationTable+'('+@DestinationFields+')values('''+REPLACE(@InsertValues,',',''',''')+''')')

Comment: @riad What's the version of your SQL Server? `REPLACE` requires SQL Server 2005 or later.

Comment: @riad You need to move the expression out of `EXEC` into a separate assignment+select, and then execute the resultant string. Take a look at this [link](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/01ea1/13), it has a working example of what you are trying to do.

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
DECLARE @DestinationFields VARCHAR(200);
SET @DestinationFields = 'Col1, Col2, Col3'

DECLARE @InsertValues VARCHAR(200);
SET @InsertValues = '1, 2, 3'

DECLARE @SQLString VARCHAR(1000);

SET @SQLString = 'INSERT INTO tbl_test (' + @DestinationFields + ') VALUES (' + @InsertValues + ')';

EXEC (@SQLString)
```

However, this is very open to SQL Injection attacks.  But, it will do what you require.

[The Curse and Blessing of Dynamic SQL](http://www.sommarskog.se/dynamic_sql.html)

Comment: I know those kind of things.Here the number of DestinationFields can be vary and values need to store into a quotation mark .Other hand my code was work fine.Please suggest me how i put quotation mark on each value